# Elasticsearch returning error whenever sending put or post requests?

Tags: json, elasticsearch

My elasticsearch works completely fine with GET request like `curl -X GET "localhost:9200"`.

However, whenever I try to add something by using post or put, it's giving me errors.

Even this simple example document (which I get from a tutorial) wouldn't work for me:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/blog/article/1' -d '{"title": "New version of Elasticsearch released!", "content": "Version 2.2 released today!", "priority": 10, "tags": ["announce", "elasticsearch", "release"] }'
```

This is the error I got:

```
{"error":"no handler found for uri [/blog/article/1] and method [PUT]"}
```

I'm always getting this kinds of errors even though I'm sure my syntax is correct

Answer (score 0):

your use of `article` in the URL is using a type, which has been long deprecated and no longer supported

please take a look at the documentation that dives into this - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/removal-of-types.html

try something like this instead;

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/blog/_doc/1' -d '{"title": "New version of Elasticsearch released!", "content": "Version 2.2 released today!", "priority": 10, "tags": ["announce", "elasticsearch", "release"], "type": "article" }'
```